# Алгоритм интерпретатора текстовой разметки

Tags: трансляция, алгоритм, компиляция, разметка, интерпретатор

Здравствуйте!
Можно немного теории/практики по созданию простейшего интерпретатора текстовой/теговой разметки. Нужно:

- Разработать тэг разметки типа шрифта,
- Разработать тэг разметки цвета текста,
- Разработать тэг разметки размера шрифта,
- Разработать тэг разметки рисунка,
- Разработать тэг разметки координат элементов на форме,
- Разработать тег фона документа,
- Разработать тег заголовка документа,
- Разработать тег новой строки.

Язык почти неважен, но предпочтительнее Lisp, C/C++, Java, Erlang, Prolog.(Я на них хоть как-то быдлокодил).
Что его подучить, что посмотреть?

---

Я понимаю что вопрос просто "перл", сказать просто "алгоритм" для целого огромнейшего раздела компьютерной науки – ничего не сказать. Но все же – накидайте материала.

Comment: Еще один сумасшедший изобретатель...

Comment: Ну почему сразу изобретатель?.. Просто нашел в интернете задание, но не знаю методов решения подобных заданий. Никогда не связывался с созданием интерпретаторов.

Comment: Понимаю что звучит наивно и как-о дурацки, но зато просто и откровенно. Да – идиот, да – клиника. Ну так что же и интерпретатор написать нельзя?! Дайте источников для изучения и лучше с большим количеством практических примеров.

Comment: Это называется [лексический анализ](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CB%E5%EA%F1%E8%F7%E5%F1%EA%E8%E9_%E0%ED%E0%EB%E8%E7) и [парсинг](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3)

Единственный источник который я знаю, это сразу по хардкору - драгонбук: Альфред В. Ахо, Моника С. Лам, Рави Сети, Джеффри Д. Ульман. Компиляторы: принципы, технологии и инструментарий. Но может по данной информации что-то и найдется еще.

Comment: >Еще один сумасшедший изобретатель..

а что, писать свои велосипеды в целях саморазвития уже сумасшествие?

Comment: @DreamChild а я и не говорил, что это плохо быть изобретателем.

Comment: @Barmaley я акцентировал внимание не на слове "изобретатель", а на слове "сумасшедший"

Answer (score 4):

Смотрите.

Если язык в ваших руках, придумайте его так, чтобы было удобно парсить. Но конечно и легко пользоваться! Попробуйте выразить на нём простую разметку, посмотрите, насколько это легко.

Я бы сделал что-то наподобие BBCode, в конце-концов, формат известен, лёгок в разборе, читаем человеческими существами, и кажется удовлетворяет вашим требованиям. (Плюс для него существуют готовые парсеры.) Для него вполне покатит recursive descent parser (лёгкая и самоочевидная штука, которую вполне можно написать вручную).

Можно ещё прагматично взять XML, тогда синтаксический анализ доверяете одной из миллиарда готовых библиотек, а сами занимаетесь реализацией семантической части.

В качестве литературы на первом месте, конечно, упомянутый в комментариях Dragon Book (классическая, но сложная книга). Если хотите начать с чего-то полегче, прочитайте 5-ую главу Вирта «Алгоритмы + структуры данных = программы», очень лёгкое и приятное введение в тематику.

Конкретный язык реально неважен. Хотя конечно если хорошо владеете Lisp'ом, о чём мы тогда говорим?

Comment: Да спасибо. Не очень Я владею. Просто лучше и быстрее всех сдавал лабы в универе=)

Comment: Главное не взять по ошибке последние издания "Алгоритмов и структур данных", там эта глава отсутствует.

Answer (score 2):

[@Mypowerfulbrain](/users/13794/mypowerfulbrain) у вас явно нелады с логикой.

Поясню:

> Разработать тэг разметки типа шрифта

это о чем? И причем здесь Lisp, C/C++, Java, Erlang, Prolog?

Если бы вопрос формулировался так:

> Разработать парсер тэга разметки типа шрифта

то не вопрос - это задача для языка программирования.

Вы разработайте свой язык разметки и спросите как написать к нему парсер, например:

```
[шрифт]Это мой текст]тфирш[
```

Это разметка и к нему написать парсер не составляет большого труда.

Comment: А можете привести пример парсера для одного любого тэга, например, шрифт определенного размера, на любом из языков(Lisp, C/C++, Java, Erlang, Prolog)?

Comment: @Mypowerfulbrain: Не бывает парсера тега, бывает парсер языка/грамматики. Пример небольшого парсера можно посмотреть, например, [тут](/questions/260060/).

Comment: @Mypowerfulbrain этого недостаточно отсутствуют прочие условия, например могут ли быть теги вложенными, могут ли иметь теги атрибуты и проч. Впрочем, в тупом случае парсер будет типа такой:

`public String getTagBody(String text, String tag) {
    String startTag="<"+tag+">";
    String endTag="<\"+tag+">";
    int startIndex=text.indexOf(startTag);
    if(startIndex==-1)
       return null;
    int endIndex=text.indexOf(startIndex+startTag.length(), endTag);
    if(endIndex==-1)
       throw MalformedTagExpeption();
    return text.subString(startIndex, endIndex);
}`

В общем нужна грамматик

Comment: Парсеры так конечно же не пишутся - за такой "код" парсера могут и валенками закидать. Обычно парсеры пишутся с хэндлерами (callback'и) - см. например [XML SAX парсер](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML)